# Using results from Neo4j .Net driver

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, .net-core

I am struggling to cast the INode results from the native Neo4j .Net driver to my own object.

```
public class User
{
    public String UUID { get; set; }
    public String firstname { get; set; }
}
```

My node as returned in Neo4j desktop browser:

```
{
  "UUID": "e0bc991a-1018-4edb-83df-771b8cee4c88",
  "firstname": "John"
}
```

C# code using Neo4jClient (this works):

```
var users = client.Cypher
.Match("(p:Person)")
.Return(p => p.As<User>())
.Results.ToList();
```

C# code using native Neo4j .Net driver (fails):

```
var users = new List<User>();
using (var session = _driver.Session())
{
  session.ReadTransaction(tx =>
  {
    var result = tx.Run("MATCH (p:Person) RETURN p").ToList();
    users = result.Select(p => p[0].As<User>()).ToList();
  });
}
```

My error message is:
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type `Neo4j.Driver.Internal.Node` to type `sandbox_neotesting.Models.User`.

Any pointers on how I can fix this? I was hoping to find a solution where I could directly cast the result to my internal model, *not having to set each property specifically*.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very quiet here, but found a working solution. I simply serialize the node's properties, then deserialize into a User object. Feel free to suggest improvements!

```
var statementText = "MATCH (p:Person) RETURN p";

var users = new List<User>();
using (var session = _driver.Session())
{
    session.ReadTransaction(tx =>
    {
        var result = tx.Run(statementText);
        foreach(var record in result)
        {
            var nodeProps = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(record[0].As<INode>().Properties);
            users.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(nodeProps));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Glad you found it, sorry for the silence. The Neo4jClient library has more means to do that: https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki#documentation